Is it possible to encrypt a message using only the recipient's Ed25519 public key?
Suppose:

Alice knows the Ed25519 public key of Bob
Bob is using his Ed25519 private key / seed in the usual way for digital signatures

Clearly, Alice can verify messages signed by Bob.
Is there any way that Alice can also safely encrypt a message for Bob so that only Bob can decrypt it, without knowing anything other than his Ed25519 public key, and without any other key agreement / interaction?

It's possible to convert an Edwards curve point to a Montgomery curve point, HOWEVER! reusing the same key for different purpose is not recommended.

Thanks @DannyNiu. I'm aware it is not standard practice! The reason for asking whether it can be done safely is a potential application where the only thing that we can guarantee to know about another user is their signing key.

Check out Ed25519 to Curve25519 in libsodium and this blog post series by Neil Madden discussing ECIES and more secure alternatives. He also has a good series on KEMs, which mentions insider vs outsider non-repudiation.
